# How to write out Gaussian Elimination steps in vanilla LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I'm trying to figure out how to replicate this step in a Gaussian Elimination problem (*which I'm pretty sure was created with LaTeX*) in my web editor with [KaTeX](https://katex.org/) support. KaTeX unfortunately doesn't support importing packages.

[image]

The closest I've been able to get is this:

[image]

```
\rightarrow 
\begin{aligned}
\begin{vmatrix} 
a && && &- &d &= &7 \\ 
& &b && &+ &d &= &9 \\ 
&& &&c &+ &d &= &4 \\ 
& && &c &+ &d &= &4
\end{vmatrix} 

\begin{matrix} 
E_1 - E_2 \rightarrow E_1 \\ \\ 
E_3 + E_2 \rightarrow E_3 \\ 
\end{matrix}
\end{aligned}
```

The primary issue I see in this rendering is that the `matrix` lines aren't aligned with the proper equations in the `vmatrix`. Does anyone know how I can get my work to more closely line up with the example image above?

Comment: `aligned` and `vmatrix` aren't defined in LaTeX.  They are in the AMS packages, however.  You also aren't allowed the blank line in a display environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the display environments are based on the `array` environment, so you can simply use that.  The only main downside is now you need to count your columns.  To get better vertical alignment, you can insert some convenient `~`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\rightarrow
\left|
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
a&&&-&d&=&7\\
&b&&+&d&=&9\\
&&c&+&d&=&4\\
&&c&+&d&=&4\\
\end{array}
\right|
~
\begin{array}{c}
E_1 - E_2 \rightarrow E_1 \\
~\\
E_3 + E_2 \rightarrow E_3 \\
~
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: code output]

Comment: Ah gotcha! The tilda is the null character I wanted... Thanks!

Comment: @ifconfig `~` is not a null character. It is a non breaking space. In math mode, you can try other space macros: `\quad`, `\,`, `\:`, `\;` or `\ `... The null character may be `\null`.

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected! Understood, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple with the `systeme` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\sysdelim{\lvert\;}{\rvert}
\systeme{a-d = 7\;,
 b + d = 9,%
  c + d = 4 ,%@
  c + d = 4}
\sysdelim . .
\hskip-1em
\systeme{E_1-E_2\to E_1, ,E_3 + E_2\to E_3,}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, my editor doesn't allow me to import packages. It renders using the KaTeX javascript library.

Comment: This package is beautiful but I my two French words are not enough for me to go through the manual :)

Comment: @Bernard Do you know a way of doing this *without* external packages?

Answer (score 0):

The result is quite poor and no match for a real solution with better methods such as `systeme`.

```
\begin{array}{|ccccccc|l}
a & & & - & d & = & 7 &
  \scriptstyle E_1-E_2\to E_1 \\
& b & & + & d & = & 9 \\
& & c & + & d & = & 4 &
  \scriptstyle E_3+E_2\to E_3 \\
& & c & + & d & = & 4
\end{array}
```

[image]